# Stuck with SetInterval ,SetTimeOut and Requestanimationframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm kind of stuck with javascript timers. I have been reading the usage of setInterval ,setTimeOut are bad they cause page reflows and repaints,instead use request animation frame

I'm stuck and could not find one resource with a good explanation of how we can do that

I want to know ,how can we replace setinterval with requestanimationframe and settimeout with requestanimationframe

```js
var x = 0;

function SayHi() {

  console.log("hi");
  console.log(x);
  ++x
  if (x >= 10)
    clearInterval(intervalid);
}

var intervalid = setInterval(SayHi, 10);
```

How can we replace the above code with requestanimationframe and how can we clear it

```js
function greetings(){
console.log("greetings to u");  
}

setTimeout(greetings,10);
```

How can we replace setimeout in the above code with requestanimationframe.

If someone can explain the difference it would be of great help

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **setTimeout()** does *something* once after a period of time.
- **setInterval()** repeatedly does *something* after each period of time.
- **requestAnimationFrame()** does *something* once when the browser is *"ready"* (to repaint).

**How are they the same?**

You can see they all want to do *something* for you.

**How are they different?**

The basic differences are when and how often your *something* gets done.  **setInterval()** is like **setTimeout()** called repeatedly. On the other hand, **requestAnimationFrame()** is like **setTimeout()** but called when the system is ready rather than after a (pseudo) fixed time.

**How can *requestAnimationFrame()* replace *setTimeout()*?**

```
function greetings(timestamp) {
    console.log("greetings to u");
}
requestAnimationFrame(greetings);
```

**How can *requestAnimationFrame()* replace *setInterval()*?**

```
var x = 0;
function SayHi(timestamp) {
    console.log(++x);
    if (x < 10) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(SayHi);
    }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(SayHi);
```

These are super simple examples based on your example code but I hope it gives you a sense of things.

You can also check out: [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) on **requestAnimationFrame()**